# Soundflower records only mono

Tags: audio, soundflower

I noticed that Soundflower only records mono here. I tried multiple different sound sources with stereo output (Ableton, iTunes, milkytracker) and I tried multiple different sound recorders (AudioXplorer, Audacity). I tried both the 2ch and 64ch mode and I checked the volume and mute information in the Audio MIDI Setup Tool to be correct. This seems to suggest that the problem is Soundflower itself and not the application using it. Has anyone encountered the same problem and has found a workaround? I am using OS X 10.13.4. Thanks and best regards